# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0 when running apache beam Windowed WordCount example

Tags: maven, apache-beam

When I try to run the WindowedWordCount example using this command:

```
mvn compile exec:java \
    -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WindowedWordCount  \
    -Dexec.args="--inputFile=pom.xml --output=counts" -Pdirect-runner
```

It gives following error `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project beam-examples-java: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 9: counts-06:40-06:50-3-of-4 -> [Help 1]`

Note: I was able to successfully run the MinimalWordCount example and WordCount example. Problem comes only when running the DebuggingWordCount example and WindowedWordCount.

I am wondering if anyone got the same issue and how you solved it.